# Like and Share button doesn't show the page tittle propertly

Tags: php, facebook, share, title, preview

I'm having this problem, with the Facebook's like & share api.

I put the code that facebook provides, just changing the "data-href" with a specific url that references a page via "php get method" in this way:

```
echo ' <li> <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.alanmarth.com/index.php?seccion=blog&id='.$entrow["identrada"].'" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div> </li>';
```

But for some strange reason, when I click on the "share" button, the title of the like shown in facebook is different than the original one, or just works in some posts.

For example:

- Url: http://www.alanmarth.com/index.php?seccion=blog&id=2

Original title: "Alan Marth :: Algoritmo de camino más corto"

Title when shared: "Alan Marth :: Blog"

Doesn't show post images in preview

But, in other's hand:

- Url: http://www.alanmarth.com/index.php?seccion=blog&id=1

Original title: "Alan Marth :: ¡Nuevo sistema de noticias!"

Title when shared: "Alan Marth :: ¡Nuevo sistema de noticias!"

It shows images in post like preview

¿Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you ever posted the link on Facebook before it was complete, go to (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to debug the url.
If this doesn't solve your problem, use facebook's open graph meta tags in the page's :

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My website" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.full_image_url.jpeg" />
```